# android用のffplayのコンパイル方法について

Tags: android, ffmpeg

android用のffplayを作成しようと思い、./configureのオプションから --disable-ffplay を削除してビルドしました。その後、ビルドが終わっても ffplay が作成されていません。

調べてみると、SDL supportがyesにならないとffplayが作成されないことがわかりました。

```
       ～省略～
SDL support               no
opencl enabled            no
texi2html enabled         yes
perl enabled              yes
pod2man enabled           yes
makeinfo enabled          no
makeinfo supports HTML    no

Enabled programs:
ffmpeg
       ～省略～
```

Ubunto上でコンパイルしているのですが、SDL supportをyesにする方法がわかりません。
android用のffplayの作成方法についてご教授ください。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422051/ffmpeg-ffplay-binary-not-getting-generated-on-compilation